# python netminko TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, paramiko

Running a simple script for backing up L2 startup configuration i always get this type of output referring TypeError:

> No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "hp_tftp.py", line 108, in 
>       net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 167, in ConnectHandler
>       return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 187, in **init**
>       self.establish_connection()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netmiko-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 650, in establish_connection
>       self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 392, in connect
>       t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 545, in start_client
>       raise e
>   TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

And this is the code:

```html
for a_device in all_devices:
 net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
 print("----------------------------------------BEGIN----------------------------------------")
 print ("\n\n>>>>>>>>> Copying Config {0} to TFTP Server <<<<<<<<<".format(a_device['device_type']))
 net_connect.send_command("copy startup-config tftp [ip_server] pdy.sw.l2.-{0}-{1}".format(a_device['ip'],date))
 time.sleep(1)
 print ("\n\n>>>>>>>>> Startup-Config Has Been Sent {0} <<<<<<<<<".format(a_device['ip']))
 print ("\n\n----------------------------------------END----------------------------------------\n\n")
```

The 108 line is from `net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)`